# How works StopUser in Locust?

Tags: python, locust

Could you help me to understand how StopUser works in Locust - I created a simple example where I have 4 users with spawn-rate 2 which means at second 2 I will have 4 working users. But if I use StopUser, the first 2 users must stop working after a task has finished, right?

```
class SimpleClass(HttpUser):
wait_time = between(1, 2)
host = "https://example.com"

@task()
def just_print(self):
    logging.debug(f"working {datetime.today().timestamp()}")
    raise StopUser
```

Configurations:

```
users: 4
spawn-rate: 2
run-time: 20
```

In the logs, there is another situation - finally, I have 6 users and first 2 users don't stop working.

```
[2022-01-19 21:21:57,560] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.main: Run time limit set to 20 seconds
[2022-01-19 21:21:57,560] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.5.1
[2022-01-19 21:21:57,561] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.runners: Ramping to 4 users at a rate of 2.00 per second
[2022-01-19 21:21:57,561] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: Ramping to {"SimpleClass": 2} (2 total users)
[2022-01-19 21:21:57,561] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: Spawning additional {"SimpleClass": 2} ({"SimpleClass": 0} already running)...
[2022-01-19 21:21:57,562] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: 2 users spawned
[2022-01-19 21:21:57,562] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: All users of class SimpleClass spawned
[2022-01-19 21:21:57,562] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: 0 users have been stopped, 2 still running
[2022-01-19 21:21:57,562] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/root: working 1642620117.562613
[2022-01-19 21:21:57,562] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/root: working 1642620117.562741
[2022-01-19 21:21:58,567] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: Ramping to {"SimpleClass": 4} (4 total users)
[2022-01-19 21:21:58,567] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: Spawning additional {"SimpleClass": 4} ({"SimpleClass": 0} already running)...
[2022-01-19 21:21:58,568] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: 4 users spawned
[2022-01-19 21:21:58,568] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: All users of class SimpleClass spawned
[2022-01-19 21:21:58,568] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: 0 users have been stopped, 4 still running
[2022-01-19 21:21:58,568] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.runners: All users spawned: {"SimpleClass": 4} (4 total users)
[2022-01-19 21:21:58,568] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/root: working 1642620118.568855
[2022-01-19 21:21:58,569] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/root: working 1642620118.569034
[2022-01-19 21:21:58,569] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/root: working 1642620118.569189
[2022-01-19 21:21:58,569] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/root: working 1642620118.56934
[2022-01-19 21:22:17,147] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.main: --run-time limit reached. Stopping Locust
[2022-01-19 21:22:17,149] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: Stopping all users
[2022-01-19 21:22:17,149] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/DEBUG/locust.runners: 0 users have been stopped, 0 still running
[2022-01-19 21:22:17,152] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.main: Running teardowns...
[2022-01-19 21:22:17,152] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.main: Shutting down (exit code 0), bye.
[2022-01-19 21:22:17,152] Andriis-MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.main: Cleaning up runner...
```

Answer (score 1):

`StopUser()` will stop executing further tasks for that user in locust load testing.
For example, If any task got failed response and because of that all the subsequent task will fail as well, in that case you can use `StopUser()` to stop executing further tasks.

Answer (score 0):

`StopUser` is internal to Locust and not intended for direct use. Users cant really be stopped. You can achieve the same effect by calling `time.sleep(999999)` or something.

Comment: But why do users stop working after 2 seconds? Run-time was 20 seconds. It is like Locust waits for users==4 -> then stops all of them.

Comment: But anyway I get your point -> to use StopUser only in the condition like that:

        with self.client.post(url_path, json=body, catch_response=True,
                              name="request name") as test_requests:
            if test_requests.status_code != 200:
                raise StopUser